# How to import driver details and Connection details without writing it manually or hard coding?

Tags: java, configuration, jdbc

```
class ConnectionUtil{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
try{  
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","oracle"); 
....
....
}
```

In the code I have manually written the driver details and connection details. So, I want to know whether I can get get/import those details in the program that is by setting `CLASSPATH` or something.

Comment: Can you put the connection string into a configuration file? CLASSPATH magic sounds like a bad idea, but a configuration file would be fairly easy to implement.

Comment: Are you asking *how* to insert this information into your program via the CLASSPATH? Or how to do that via an external config file? Or how to compute what those values are supposed to be at runtime? Or which of those you *should* be doing? (only the last question would be on-topic here, as the others are implementation details that belong on StackOverflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you not use a config file ? Those kind of file is easy to read with java.

You could use [this tutorial](http://crunchify.com/java-properties-file-how-to-read-config-properties-values-in-java/) to build your own config system

Comment: Thank you I have written the code using config file. But I still have a doubt whether we can set driver details, URL, username, password as environmental variables and then getting those values using System.getProperties().